# millisecond epoch conversion in Sybase ASE

Tags: sap-ase

I have a column of epochs in millisecond format.
I need to convert them to another column of datetime including millisecond accuracy.

i have tried all sorts of combinations of (with cast, convert, etc):

```
select dateadd(ss, 1610309854301, '19700101')
```

I keep getting:

```
Arithmetic overflow during explicit conversion of BIGINT value '1610309854301'
```

There are some comments on previous posts, but none that work on ASE.

Need to get 1610309854301: this to equal this in another column.
Sunday, 10 January 2021 20:17:34.301

Can this be done in SQL on ASE 16.1?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Running a few quick tests it looks (to me) like some of the date-related functions have not been updated to work with `bigint` datatypes (eg, documentation for `dateadd()` only mentions `int` values as arguments).

Assuming you have a support contract, I'd suggest opening a case with SAP to see if this is a known issue (and if a fix is planned/available in a future version), or if there's a preferred workaround.

---

A simple workaround would be to break the `bigint` value into 2 chunks ... `/1000` => number of seconds ... `%1000` => number of milliseconds ... and then paste back together for the desired result, eg:

```
declare @ms     bigint,
        @newdt  datetime,         -- limited to 3 millisec precision
        @newdtb bigdatetime,      -- supports microsecs so not limited to mod(3 msec)
        @newdts varchar(30)       -- collect strings to convert into (big)datetime

select  @ms     = 1610309854301
select  @newdts = convert(varchar(30),dateadd(ss, @ms/1000, '19700101'),116) + '.' +
                  right('000'+convert(varchar(3),@ms % 1000),3 )
select  @newdt  = convert(datetime,@newdts)
select  @newdtb = convert(bigdatetime,@newdts)

select @newdts, convert(varchar(30),@newdt,139), convert(varchar(30),@newdtb,139)
go
```

This generates:

```
 ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------
 Jan 10 2021 20:17:34.301       Jan 10 2021 20:17:34.300000    Jan 10 2021 20:17:34.301000
```

**NOTES**:

- the 2nd value (`@newdt`) demonstrates `ASE's` limitation on `datetime` datatypes (ie, 3 millisec precision)
- above was tested on `ASE 16.0 SP03 PL07`

Answer (score 0):

Not perfect but ...

dateadd(second , (number_of_millis / 1000), "01-01-1970")

e.g. dateadd(second , (1610309854301 / 1000), "01-01-1970")

If you use seconds, you get an overflow error.

or if using as part of a select

select dateadd(second , CONVERT(INT, (my_milli_second_column / 1000)), "01-01-1970")